# React Native- Trouble implementing Redux into my multipage Registration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, registration

I am attempting to convert my single page registration into a multi page registration form and am trying to accomplish this by using Redux.

The action file looks like this where RegisterA1 refers to the first page of the registration and RegisterA2 refers to the second page of the registration.

```js
export const RegisterA1 = (email, password) => {
    return {
        type: 'REGISTER1',
        email: email,
        password: password
    };
};

export const RegisterA2 = (first, last, dob) => {
    return {
        type: 'REGISTER2',
        first: first,
        last: last,
        dob: dob
    };
};
```

The reducer file looks like this:

```js
const defaultState = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    first: '',
    last:'',
    dob:'',
};

export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REGISTER1': 
            return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                email: action.email,
                password: action.password,
            });
        case 'REGISTER2' :
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                first: action.first,
                last: action.last,
                dob: action.dob,
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Now in the first file I try to build a screen with two fields and a button which when pressed navigates to the next screen and also saves the new input to the redux store. **MY PROBLEM LIES HERE** as the `this.props.onRegisterA1(this.state.email, this.state.password );`
 is said to be undefined.

Please review the whole screen code here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
import { AppRegistry,TextInput,View,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; //navigation between pages
import { FormLabel, FormInput,Button,Text } from 'react-native-elements'; //ui 
import  store  from '../store/store'
import { Provider } from  'react-redux';
import Register2   from './namefields';
import { RegisterA1 } from '../actions/registration';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';



let styles = {}

class Register1 extends React.Component{ 
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  empaRegister (e) {
      this.props.onRegisterA1( this.state.email, this.state.password );
      e.preventDefault();
      const { navigate  } = this.props.navigation;
      navigate('Register2')
       }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <FormLabel
          containerStyle={styles.labelContainerStyle}>Email</FormLabel>
        <FormInput
          ref='form2'
          containerRef='containerRefYOYO'
          textInputRef='textInputRef'
          placeholder='Please enter your email address...'
          onChangeText = {(newValue) =>this.setState({email:newValue})}
        />
        <FormLabel containerStyle={styles.labelContainerStyle}>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput 
          ref='form1' 
          placeholder='Please create a password...'
          onChangeText ={(newValue) =>this.setState({password:newValue}) }
        />
        <Button title="Next" onPress={(e) =>this.empaRegister(e)}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
     }

const emailandpass = StackNavigator({
  Register1: {screen: Register1  },
  Register2: {screen: Register2}
});

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    email: state.userReducer.email,
    password: state.userReducer.password
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onregister1: (email, password) => { dispatch(register1(email, password)); }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register1);
module.exports = emailandpass ;
```

The entry React component looks like this

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/store/store';
import Application from './src/components/Landingscreen';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Application />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('LearnD', () => App);
```

Feeding into a "Landingscreen" which prompts the registration screens.

This is the store:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';

let store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

The error looks like this

[image]

Any help would be appreciated,

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your actions, reducer, `mapStateToProps`, and `mapDispatchToProps` all look good, as far as I can tell. But you are importing `Provider` and `store` apparently without using them. (Could you also show the `store` file?)

Check out the Redux docs for how you use `Provider` to allow the `store` to be accessed with `connect`ed components: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#passing-the-store

Essentially, whereever your root React component is, it has to have this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MyTopLevelComponent/>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prop in is onregister1 not onRegisterA1, so onRegisterA1 is undefined